# Add session id to each log in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to add the session id to each log in Rails.

Now, I've added this in my environment.rb:

```
class Logger
  def format_message(severity, timestamp, progname, msg)
    "#{timestamp.to_formatted_s(:db)} #{severity} #{msg}\n" 
  end 
end
```

First of all, is this best-practice? And how do I add the session id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you are working with rails 3.2 you can use log tags:

> Update Rails::Rack::Logger middleware to apply any tags set in
>   config.log_tags to the newly ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging
>   Rails.logger. This makes it easy to tag log lines with debug
>   information like subdomain and request id -- both very helpful in
>   debugging multi-user production applications DHH

with some luck, adding this to your environment might work:

```
config.log_tags = [:uuid, :remote_ip, :session_id]
```

UPDATE

for the unlucky, the solution is from the answer of @shigeya.

unfortunately rails does NOT provide a way to access your sessionid in a sane manner.
you always have to rely on what rack is doing in it's internals... accessing the cookie_jar with your cookie key is the "recommended" way of doing so.

this is what i use for my application:

```
config.log_tags = [
  :host,
  :remote_ip,
  lambda { |request| "#{request.uuid}"[0..15] },
  lambda { |request| "#{request.cookie_jar["_session_id"]}"[0..15] },
]
```

output then looks like this:

```
[hamburg.onruby.dev] [127.0.0.1] [27666d0897c88b32] [BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Np] Completed 200 OK in 298ms (Views: 286.2ms | ActiveRecord: 9.2ms)
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work. depending on your value of "luck." I suppose you could monkey patch the Request object to get it working, but shigeya's solution actually does work. To be specific, any symbols passed here will be methods called on the Request object.

Comment: It should be noted that this does NOT give you the session_id of the request.  It's actually reading the entire Base64 encoded cookie.  So you'll find the vast majority of your users have "BAh7C0kiD3Nlc3Np"  because that's the first 16 chars of Base64 encoding: '{I"session_id'.

Comment: @DrewBlas that does not matter. this piece of information is enough to track a user through his requests and will not change until he has a new session.

Comment: On Rails4, in development, the value is different on each request

Comment: this might have changed because the values of cookies are encrypted by default nowadays i think

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, giving `:session_id` to `log_tags` don't work yet (as of May 23 2012), since there is no session_id in Rack middleware.

Since log_tags array accept a Proc object, and the proc object is invoked with a request object, I could configure the log_tags following way:

```
config.log_tags = [ :uuid, :remote_ip,
                    lambda {|req| "#{req.cookie_jar["_session_id"]}" } ]
```

It's working with Rails 3.2.3, with ActiveRecord's session store is in use.

Comment: Note that "_session_id" may be set to something else in your config/initializers/session_store.rb

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 3.2 with `ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging`, if you're using `:cookie_store`:

```
config.log_tags = [ :uuid, :remote_ip, 
                    lambda { |r| "#{r.cookie_jar.signed["_session_id"]["session_id"]}" } ]
```

Note: Change the `"_session_id"` with your `:key` value at `config/initializers/session_store.rb`

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately this isn't easy with Rails log tags. Moreover, it clutters your logs to the point where they are unreadable.

I'd recommend something like [timber](https://github.com/timberio/timber-ruby), it captures session ids (and more) by simply augmenting your logs with metadata. It's automatic and you don't lose readability.